# How to debug 'df' is not defined?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I don't know why "df" is not defined because i already assigned df a value.

```py
import pandas as pd 
ListOfProduct=[]
ListOfProduct.append((ProID, Proname, Price))
data_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ProID': ProID,
        'Proname':Proname,
        'Price':Price,
})

df=pd.DataFrame(ListOfProduct, columns=['ProID', 'Proname','Price'])
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)

datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')
filename = 'qc_out_{}'.format(datestring)
f = open(filename, 'w') 

df.to_csv( filename+'.csv', header=True, index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig') --> This line is error
```

Comment: You are not creating `df` anywhere. Just writing df into a `csv`.

Comment: There should be  a data frame assigned to `df` before attempting to write it to a CSV

Comment: How to  creat df?@MayankPorwal

Comment: My code

df=pd.DataFrame(ListOfProduct, columns=['productID', 'productname','price')
                     pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)

datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')
filename = 'qc_out_{}'.format(datestring)
f = open(filename, 'w') 

df.to_csv( filename+'.csv', header=True, index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')

Mycode @MayankPorwal

Comment: @JatupornJirundorn Please paste your code in question iteself. Not in comments.

Comment: @MayankPorwal Ok

Answer (score 0):

you have a stray single quote that makes most of your code a string literal.  Change `'ProID'': ProID,` to `'ProID': ProID`.

Comment: the syntax coloring should tip you off to this

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
ListOfProduct=[]
ListOfProduct.append((ProID, Proname, Price))
data_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ProID': ProID,
        'Proname':Proname,
        'Price':Price,
})

df=pd.DataFrame(ListOfProduct, columns=['ProID', 'Proname','Price'])
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)

datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S')
filename = 'qc_out_{}'.format(datestring)
f = open(filename, 'w') 

df.to_csv( filename+'.csv', header=True, index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: You wrote ListOfProduct = [ ] and I wrote code same you but It 's same error this line is
df.to_csv( filename+'.csv', header=True, index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')

Comment: Here, Jatuporn my bad, Try this now